# How to initialize multiple constant member variables that shares complex initialization code?

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, member-initialization

#### Introduction

Let's introduce this simple example:

```
#include <cmath>

class X
{
public: // Members

    /// A ^ B + A
    int A;

    /// A ^ B + B
    int B;

public: // Specials

    X(
        const int & A,
        const int & B
    )
        : A(A)
        , B(B)
    {
        const auto Pow = static_cast<int>(std::pow(A, B));

        this->A += Pow;
        this->B += Pow;
    }
};
```

#### Trivia

- Introduced class has two member variables: `A` and `B`.
- They take value of `A ^ B + A` and `A ^ B + B`, respectively.
- Both of them shares common complex initialization code (let's assume `std::pow` is complex).

#### Problem

I'd like to make both `A` and `B` members `const`.

#### Question

How to do that without repeating complex initialization (*ie* avoid calling `std::pow` twice)?

#### What I've tried

```
#include <cmath>

class X
{
public: // Members

    /// A ^ B + A
    const int A;

    /// A ^ B + B
    const int B;

public: // Helpers

    struct Init
    {
    public: // Members

        int A;
        int B;

    public: // Specials

        Init(
            const int & A,
            const int & B
        )
            : A(A)
            , B(B)
        {
            const auto Pow = static_cast<int>(std::pow(A, B));

            this->A += Pow;
            this->B += Pow;
        }
    };

public: // Specials

    X(
        const Init& Init
    )
        : A(Init.A)
        , B(Init.B)
    {};

    X(
        const int & A,
        const int & B
    )
        : X(Init(
            A,
            B
        ))
    {};
};
```

1. Create `struct Init` that takes role of past version of class `X`.
2. Make `X` members `const` while keep `Init` members non `const`.
3. Use constructor delegation to redirect constructor arguments to `Init`.
4. Move non `const` member variables from `Init` to `X` and make them `const`.

   - Note there is no `std::move` as `int` is [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable).

However, my solution seems overcomplicated. Any help would be appreciated.

#### No goals

- Make another `X` member variable that will store common code result (*ie* `std::pow`).
- Add another level of indirection outside `X` class (*eg* introduce base class for `X`).

#### Note

Solutions can use newer versions of C++ than C++11.

Comment: Have you considered making the members private, and non-const, and only making accessors? That's the normal way to enable this kind of functionality.

Comment: I want to use `const` as I will be storing those values until program exits (_eg_ for many hours), not because I don't want them to be edited/visible, so getters/setters is not my goal here.

Comment: Duration of the variables will be the duration of the class instance, regardless of them being `const` or non-`const`. were you thinking of `static`?

Comment: Also, have you considered that you may not have C++11 enabled? your code works fine for me when I put `Init init(1,2); X x(init); std::cout << x.A << " " << x.B << std::endl;` in my main, the output is `2 3`.

Comment: There will be many instances of this class in my code, so `static` in not an option. I have `std::latest` in my code, and it utilizies many C++17 and one C++20 feautures right now, so I do, definitelly, have C++11 enabled. My problem is solved already btw, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a [delegating constructor](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor) is a good option for such cases.

```
class X
{
   public: // Members

      /// A ^ B + A
      const int A;

      /// A ^ B + B
      const int B;

   public:

      X(int a, int b) : X(a, b, func1(a, b)) {}

   private:

      X(int a, int b, int c) : A(func2(a, b, c)), B(func3(a, b, c)) {}

      static int func1(int a, int b) { return std::pow(a,b); }
      static int func2(int a, int b, int c) { return (a + c); }
      static int func3(int a, int b, int c) { return (b + c); }
};
```

The logic/computation in `func1`, `func2`, and `func3` can be as simple or as complex as you need.

Comment: This is exactly what I've missed, thanks :)

Rationale: While NathanOliver's answer solves problem too, it adds requirement to use different name to initialize class (_ie_ `X::make` instead of just `X`). I've marked your answer as solution as it adds no such requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by using a factory function.  You make the constructor of `X` private and then use a friend/static function to get objects of `X`.  Then you can do the complex code in the body of the function and then pass those values to the constructor of X.  That would look something like

```
class X
{
public:
    const int A;
    const int B;
    friend X make_X(int a, int b)
    {
        // do complex stuff
        return X(complex_result1, complex_result2);
    }
    // or
    static X make(int a, int b)
    {
        // do complex stuff
        return X(complex_result1, complex_result2);
    }
private:
    X(const int  A, const int  B) : A(A), B(B) {}
};
```

and would be used like

```
X foo = make_x(a, b);
//or
X foo = X::make(a, b);
```

Comment: I feel like it would be cleaner by using a delegating constructor rather than a friend function?

Comment: You can also make it a static member `make(int, int)`, and write `X::make(a,b)` instead of `make_X(a,b)`

Comment: @chtz Yep.  I've added that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Borgleader I feel you're right.  The more I look at R Sahu's answer the more I like it.