# Implementation of composition - avoiding initializer list

Tags: c++, list, composition, initializer

I like to make a composition between classes A and B - say, class B has a member which is of type A. Prior to initialization of this member, some calculations and/ or further steps are needed as one of the constructor's (of class A) parameters need to be worked out. Hence initialization via initializer list is adverse.

The only way to get this to work is to do some preliminary initialization of member of type A in the constructor/initialization list (of class B) and then override this member further down in the constructer once the parameter has been obtained.

```
class A{
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    A(int x, int y): a(x), b(y) {}
}

class B{
private:
    A objA;
public:
    B(){
    // some necessary steps to get say variable int w
    objA = new A(w, w+1); // late initialization causes compile error, as
                        // all members need to be init once entering Ctor
}
```

I guess there is a more elegant solution than the one mentioned earlier: double initialization - first in initialization list (e.g. via B(): objA(0,0)), later as needed (A(w,w+1)).
Thank you!

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382549/how-to-initialize-multiple-constant-member-variables-that-shares-complex-initial

Comment: depending on what the "necessary steps" are, you could extract them into a static function, returning w or an instance of A. The second might be a constructor of A. Btw.: Do not assign a pointer to an Object!

Answer (score 1):

Use delegating constructor:

```
class B{
private:
    A objA;
public:
    B() : B(compute_w()){}

private:
    B(int w) : A(w, w+1) {}
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that one, which I am going to use. The only downside is that an additional member function (e.g. compute_w() ) needs to be added. Sometimes this might result in better readability, though.